# rpm's %pretrans, %pre, etc. scriptlet section doesn't seem to support /bin/sh

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

Does rpm's %pretrans, %pre, %post, etc. scriptlet sections not support all of /bin/sh?

```
%pretrans
[ -n "$VERBOSE" ] && echo "pretrans called with argument \`$1'" >&2
[ -n "$VERBOSE" ] && set -x

%preun
```

The above gives the following error when the rpm is installed

```
# rpm -i dist/mapr-bogus-0.0.0-1.noarch.rpm 
error: %pretrans(mapr-bogus-0.0.0-1.noarch) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
```

If I add an "echo hello" under the conditional statements the rpm installs without errors.  Is there a rule regarding short-circuit conditionals in rpm scriptlets?

```
bash-4.1# rpmbuild --version
RPM version 4.8.0
bash-4.1# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.1 (Final)
Release:    6.1
Codename:   Final
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RPM scriptlet fails (as every shell script) when last command fails. When '$VERBOSE' is empty, then '[' returns 1:

```
$ [ -n "$VERBOSE" ]
$ echo $?
1
```

Because you use && nothing else is executed. So last command exit with status code 1, therefore whole scriptlet end with status code 1. This RPM evaluate that scriptlet failed.

Correct solution can be:

```
%pretrans
[ -n "$VERBOSE" ] && echo "pretrans called with argument \`$1'" >&2
[ -n "$VERBOSE" ] && set -x
:
```

where ':' is common alias for 'true'.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to @msuchy's answer:

Another way to suppress the error the "right" way, and will also work if you're running under "set -e", is to invert the test so it's always true:

```
[ -z "$VERBOSE" ] || echo "thingywhatsit"
```

If $VERBOSE is empty, the first test will be true and the echo is not run. If it's false, it'll run the echo, and it'll be an error only if echo returned an error. This is just about exactly what you want.

And remember that run inside things like "if" statements don't trigger failures: $? is 0, unless something in the "then" or "else" blocks creates an error.